# How to rollback uncommited relationship after using pushObject?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given a `tag` and `post` ManyToMany relationship defined as follow:

*post.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  tags: hasMany('tag')
}
```

*tag.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  posts: hasMany('post')
}
```

When adding `tags` to `post` using `pushObject`

```
let aPost = this.store.findRecord('post', 1),
    aTag  = this.store.findRecord('tag', 1);

aPost.get('tags').pushObject(aTag); // aPost is not commited yet
```

How to restore `aPost.tags` to its initial state?